# Using group_by inside a function

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write a function, using `dplyr` syntax, which includes grouping with group_by inside the function. There seems to be a problem with the `group_by` statement, and I can't figure out whats wrong. When I pass `abc` as an argument and using `select` inside the function, it works as i would have expected (Gfunc1). When trying to `group_by` the same argument, it gives me an error;

> Error: Column `dims` is unknown

Please see exampel below. I really hope I have not overlooked some embarrassingly simple thing... anyway, would be gratefull for help!

```
library(dplyr)


abc <- c("a","a","a","b","b","c")
num <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) 
df <- data.frame(abc,num)


Gfunc1 <- function(dims) {
test1 <- df %>% 
    select(dims)
assign("test1", test1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

Gfunc2 <- function(dims) {
test2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(dims)

assign("test2", test2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

Gfunc1("abc") 
# Returns as expected; df test1 with only col = "abc"

Gfunc2("abc")
# Does not return what i expect; gives error:  Error: Column `dims` is unknown
```

Comment: Use `group_by_at(dims)".

Answer (score 3):

One can solve this by using `{{}}`(I'm using `rlang` 0.4.1, `dplyr` 0.8.3) as follows.

The issue is that one needs to do a bit of extra work when writing functions that depend on `dplyr`. This is often done via tidy evaluation/Non Standard Evaluation(NSE). I added `df` as an argument because I feel it is always better to provide the dataset as an argument rather than calling it from an external environment.
Why `Gfunc1` works is to do with `select` being more robust unlike other `dplyr` functions:

```
Gfunc2 <- function(df = NULL,dims) {
  test2 <- df %>% 
    group_by({{dims}})

  assign("test2", test2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

For earlier versions of `rlang` and `dplyr`, the same can be achieved using `sym` and `!!`:

```
Gfunc2 <- function(df = NULL,dims) {
  test2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(dims))

  assign("test2", test2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
Gfunc2(df,"abc")
```

**NOTE**

1. It is almost always better to store results in a list instead of sending them to `.GlobalEnv`.

Comment: Good solution. Mine covers a new approach that Rstudio shared recently

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Did not know that about dplyr i functions... both that and the !!sum() and the  {{}} are real key pieces not only to this particular question, but overall. All this PLUS outing in list instead of changing envir == to service. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function by passing the dots to it. This way you can group by and select more than one variable at the time using NSE.

```
Gfunc1 <- function(.df, ...) {
  test1 <- .df %>%
    select(...)

  assign("test1", test1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

Gfunc2 <- function(.df, ...) {

    test2 <- .df %>%
      group_by(...)

    assign("test2", test2, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }

 Gfunc1(df, abc)
 Gfunc2(df, abc)
```

**results**

```
> test1
  abc
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   b
5   b
6   c

test2 %>%
   summarise(sum = sum(num))

  abc     sum
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a         6
2 b         9
3 c         6
```

To see more about this, consider the material from the RstudioConf selecting and doing with the Tidy Eval
- [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/lionelhenry/selecting-and-doing-with-tidy-eval)
- [video](https://resources.rstudio.com/rstudio-conf-2019/working-with-names-and-expressions-in-your-tidy-eval-code)

Comment: Hey Johan, I have not tried your approach yet, but will do so next time I get the opportunity.  I am sure it works perfectly. Thank you so much for answering!